# How do I disable pyarrow using data bricks

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, databricks

I'm trying to convert a pyspark dataframe to pandas data frame in databricks. My databricks Runtime version is 7.3 LTS (Scala 2.12, Spark 3.0.1)
So I wrote following code

```
df_temp=spark_temp.toPandas()
```

But I'm getting error message

```
UserWarning: toPandas attempted Arrow optimization because 'spark.sql.execution.arrow.enabled' is set to true,
```

So I tried following to disable the pyarrow

```
spark.conf.set(“spark.sql.execution.arrow.enabled”, “false”)
```

But I'm getting error message

```
SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier
```

And it's pointing to spark.sql
Can you help me to resolve the issue

Comment: can you point me from which page have you copied that piece of code? I can help fix it if it's from the Databricks pages

Answer (score 5):

The issue is from those double quotation marks, try this:

spark.conf.set("spark.sql.execution.arrow.enabled", "false")